# What was Ben' motivation in "At Last"?

Tags: true-blood

At the end of Season 6 Episode 4, "At Last", Ben and Niall have a confrontation after

> Niall figures out that "Ben" is actuall Warlow

which ends badly for Niall

> who is thrown into the same Farie "prison" that Warlow just escaped from.

Given that Ben is supposed to be a "good guy", why did he respond as he did?

Comment: just FYI: for an episode this recent, you're asking a nearly unanswerable question because *we don't know yet* what Ben's real motive is. However, the comment about him being a "good guy" inspired me to answer anyway.

Answer (score 2):

"Good" and "Evil" are very fuzzy concepts in True Blood. Many of the characters we consider "protagonists" have committed multiple instances of mass murder over the course of the seasons. I can't actually think of a single character that hasn't done *something* seriously immoral and/or illegal at some point. That's part of the point of the show -- the interaction  between humans and supernaturals is given a nice, friendly veneer thanks to TrueBlood, but in reality it's a deadly conflict with both sides acting out their baser survival instincts, often to bad ends.

As far as the specific character of Ben:

> we have no idea how good/bad of a character he is yet. He did murder a large portion of Sookie's family, but he was doing it to save her life. Does that make him "good"?

We don't know his end-game, or what he really wants from Sookie. We mostly have his word on those things, and so far no one in this show has been hesitant to lie their ass off to get what they want.